# Why are my ASP validators not using javascript?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, validation

I want to use the ASP validators: Requiredfieldvalidator, Regularexpressionvalidator.
I'm using visual studio 2013 and don't have anything about validations in my web.config.

The problem is that no javascript validation is used on the page, I did include this line in my global.asax file in the application_start method:

```
ScriptManager.ScriptResourceMapping.AddDefinition("jquery", new ScriptResourceDefinition { Path = "~/js/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"});
```

The path is correct and the jquery file is in there.

Requested ASPX page:

```
<label>Naam</label>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox_name" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="Naam" CausesValidation="true" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator_name" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Vul uw naam in" Display="None" ControlToValidate="TextBox_name"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
<asp:Button ID="Button_send" runat="server" Text="Verstuur" CssClass="btn btn-default" OnClick="Button_send_Click" CausesValidation="true" />
```

Comment: Without the actual .aspx code is difficult to understand what you are refering to.. but if you meant to use `RequiredFieldValidator` the javascript code it refers to doesn't rely upon JQuery or other JS libs but it's selft generated by ASP itself.

Comment: @weirdgyn Added the aspx page code. Normally when you press tab twice without putting anything inside the textbox while it has an requiredfieldvalidator on it, this would show the error of the validator right? in my case this doesn't happen.

Comment: So is `Display="None"` on purpose? Or was that a mistake? 'Cause that's most likely your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to see a validation indicator on the client side, you can define the Text property of the validator, and set its `Display` property to `Dynamic` or `Static`:

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator Display="Dynamic" Text="Missing value!" ForeColor="Red" ... />
```

Please note, however, that the validation will be triggered only if some change has been made to the text before it loses the focus (removing the whole content, in this case).

If you want to force the validation every time the TextBox loses the focus, even when no change has been made to its content, you can handle the `blur` event:

```
<asp:TextBox onblur="validateText();" ... />
```

with the following event handler:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function validateText() {
        var validator = document.getElementById('<%= RequiredFieldValidator_name.ClientID %>');
        if (validator) {
            ValidatorValidate(validator);
        }
    }    
</script>
```

Comment: You're completly right, this answered my question. Thanks alot!